# How to flip an imageview in the UIAlertView in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uialertview

I have an `AlertView` with an `imageView` and I have to show the image in flip animation (`UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft`/`Right`) as a `subview` of alert view

I am using the following method

```
- (void) setAnimationFlip:(UIAlertView*)alertView {

    UIView *containerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 40, 150, 150)];
    UIImageView *mainView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scene1.jpg"]];
    UIImageView *flipToView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"scene2.jpg"]];

    mainView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 200, 210);
    flipToView.frame = CGRectMake(20, 40, 200, 210);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];

    [UIView setAnimationTransition:([mainView superview] ?
                                    UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft : UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight)
                           forView:containerView cache:YES];
    if ([flipToView superview])
    {
        [flipToView removeFromSuperview];
        [containerView addSubview:mainView];

    }
    else
    {
        [mainView removeFromSuperview];
        [containerView addSubview:flipToView];
    }

    [self.alrtViewPreview addSubview:containerView];
    [self.alrtViewPreview show];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

    //[containerView release];
    //[mainView release];
    //[flipToView release];

}
```

and calling like...

```
    switch (iEffect) {
            case 1:

                [self setAnimationFlip:alrtViewPreview];
                break;
    }
```

but it is not working for me, can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)btnClick:(UIButton*)sender {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:sender cache:YES]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.tileImage]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [sender setTitle:self.tileText forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Using an animation block is preferred over the "old" animation code.